# Azure deployement seems not working with my web-service in Java EE with IntelliJ and Azure tools

Tags: java, azure, web-services, jakarta-ee, web-deployment

I did a webservice in Java EE in SCRUD. I try to put it on Azure web-app because I would like to use it for another project and it will be easier if I can put it on it. But when I deploy it on Azure, I only have acces at the index.jsp page.

My classes are like that:

```
@Path("LikePost")
public class LikePostAPI extends RestApplication {
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("GetAll")
public Response getAll(){
    Connection conn= GetConnection.getInstance().getConnection();
    Response response= Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(new DaoLikePost(conn).getAll()).build();
    return response;
}
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("getLike")
public Response getLike(@QueryParam("id") int id) {
    Response response=null;
    Connection conn=GetConnection.getInstance().getConnection();
    Like l=new DaoLikePost(conn).find(id);
    if(l!=null)
        response=Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(l).build();
    else
        response=Response.status(Response.Status.NO_CONTENT).entity(null).build();
    return response;
}
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("CreateLike")
public Response createLike(@FormParam("dateLiked") String dateLike,@FormParam("user") String userId,@FormParam("post") String postId){
    Connection conn=GetConnection.getInstance().getConnection();
    Like l=new Like();
    l.setUser(new DaoUser(conn).find(Integer.parseInt(userId)));
    DateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
    Date date=null;
    try {
        date=dateFormat.parse(dateLike);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    l.setDateLiked(date);
    l.setPost(new DaoPost(conn).find(Integer.parseInt(postId)));
    Boolean test=new DaoLikePost(conn).create(l);
    Response response=null;
    if(test)
        response=Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(test).build();
    else
        response=Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(test).build();
    return response;
}
@DELETE
@Path("DeleteLike")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response deleteLike(@QueryParam("id")int id){
    Connection conn=GetConnection.getInstance().getConnection();
    Like l=new DaoLikePost(conn).find(id);
    Boolean test=new DaoLikePost(conn).delete(l);
    Response response=null;
    if(test)
        response=Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(test).build();
    else
        response=Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(null).build();
    return response;
}
@PUT
@Path("UpdateLike")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response updateLike(@FormParam("id") String idLike,@FormParam("dateLiked") String dateLike,@FormParam("user") String userId,@FormParam("post") String postId){
    Connection conn=GetConnection.getInstance().getConnection();
    Like l=new Like();
    l.setId(Integer.parseInt(idLike));
    l.setUser(new DaoUser(conn).find(Integer.parseInt(userId)));
    Date date=null;
    DateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
    try {
        date=dateFormat.parse(dateLike);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    l.setDateLiked(date);
    l.setPost(new DaoPost(conn).find(Integer.parseInt(postId)));
    Boolean test=new DaoLikePost(conn).update(l);
    Response response=null;
    if(test)
        response=Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(test).build();
    else
        response=Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(null).build();
    return response;
}
}
```

here's the configuration for the deployement: https://gyazo.com/fed4d79d5d3cb72a820073efd234feb2

for the artifacts exploded: https://gyazo.com/a948f72cff3b89fd86df7d820aa928eb

and for the war file: https://gyazo.com/7ac6ead33bd6a129a4ad2a7ec537acd0

The Azure website is: https://faceapibook.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Tomcat 8.5 only provides implementations of Servlet 3.1 and JSP 2.3. It is not a complete Java EE implementation. In particular, it does not implement any JAX-RS functionality.

Comment: oh! okay ! What I need to use then?

Comment: I only can take Tomcat or jetty :/ I don't know if it will work ith jetty

Comment: You need to find out how to add a JAX-RS implementation to Tomcat. It's not something I ever bother with. I just use WildFly or Payara or TomEE or GlassFish or WebSphere Liberty.

Comment: Okay thx a lot. I need to use it for school and that's horrible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, without Azure using IntelliJ, you have to make sure your application will be running normally in Tomcat or Jetty on your local machine.

Then you can follow the two offical tutorials below to directly deploy it to Azure in your IntelliJ with Azure Toolkit plugin.

1. [Create a Hello World web app for Azure using IntelliJ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/intellij/azure-toolkit-for-intellij-create-hello-world-web-app?toc=%2Fen-us%2Fjava%2Fazure%2Fintellij%2Ftoc.json%3Fview%3Dazure-java-stable&bc=%2Fen-us%2Fjava%2Fjava_sdk_breadcrumb%2Ftoc.json%3Fview%3Dazure-java-stable&view=azure-java-stable)
2. [Publish a Spring Boot app as a Docker container by using the Azure Toolkit for IntelliJ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/intellij/azure-toolkit-for-intellij-publish-spring-boot-docker-app?view=azure-java-stable)

Besides, if you can make your exported war file works in your local tomcat server, you also can follow the section [`Deploy WAR file`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip#deploy-war-file) of the offical document `Deploy your app to Azure App Service with a ZIP or WAR file` to deploy the war file exported from your IntelliJ project, and see more details from the wiki page [`Deploying WAR files using wardeploy`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-WAR-files-using-wardeploy).

Even, when you correctly set the value of Java version in the tab `Application settings` of Azure portal, as below, you can upload the war file into the `webapps` directory under the path `wwwroot` of Kudo console directly to complete the deployment.